# Persisting entity with foreign key to existing entity

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have a `User` entity which has a `ManyToOne` relationship with a `UserGroup` entity. I have a form that constructs a `User` entity with a selected `UserGroup` based on a select element that is populated with values from the database. An example object looks like this:

```
object(User\Entity\User)[407]
  protected 'id' => null
  protected 'username' => string 'SomeTest' (length=8)
  protected 'password' => string '$2y$12$9mOe1ebW/bfpzXHZ.SoKx.B6PpWpogkXq/OIwFajojo3lpDmcY3ma' (length=60)
  protected 'email' => string 'test@test.com' (length=13)
  protected 'firstName' => string 'First' (length=5)
  protected 'lastName' => string 'Last' (length=4)
  protected 'isActive' => boolean true
  protected 'group' => 
    object(User\Entity\UserGroup)[507]
      protected 'id' => int 2
      protected 'name' => string 'Salesman' (length=8)
```

In this example, the user group with ID 2 already exists in the database. The problem is that in my `user` table, the `user_group_id` column is not populated. Rather, when I persist the entity, it is left empty (it is temporarily nullable). Below are my two entities and the code to persist the entity.

**User**

```
namespace User\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="mydb.user")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    // Some fields left out

    /**
     * @var UserGroup
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User\Entity\UserGroup")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_group_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $group;


    // Getters and setters
}
```

**UserGroup**

```
namespace User\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="mydb.user_group")
 */
class UserGroup
{
    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $name;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

**Business logic**

```
public function create(\User\Entity\User $user)
{
    // Simplified code
    $this->objectManager->persist($user);
    $this->objectManager->flush();
}
```

I tried many variations of the above, but the problem is that the `user_group_id` foreign key is always left empty in my `user` table. I was searching a lot for a solution, but I haven't been able to find one. I have a feeling that there is a dead simple solution to this and that I am missing something. What's wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your business logic is a type hint called UserEntity. Is this just an alias to User?

Comment: @SenseException Yes, that is correct. I will add a phpDoc declaration. Sorry about that.

Comment: You write the group in User is temporary nullable. Does this mean that the User is saved first without a group and then it is added after? Before you persist and flush the User, does it contain the group at that point?

Comment: @SenseException The column in the database is nullable due to existing users, but this will be changed later. The object is as the example object in the question when I persist and flush the user. So the object has a group before I do anything related to persistence/doctrine. The logic in the question is all of the code responsible for saving the user. I hope that answers your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might come from an issue in doctrine owning / inverse side concept, more explanation [here](http://jeremymarc.github.io/2013/01/31/symfony-form-and-doctrine-inverse-side-association/)

You need to add the inversedBy property in User, add a property $users in Group and customize the auto-generated setter in UserGroup.

### User

```
class User
{
    /**
     * @var UserGroup
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User\Entity\UserGroup", inversedBy="users")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_group_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
     protected $group;
}
```

### UserGroup

```
class UserGroup
{
    /**
     * @var User
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="group")
     */
     protected $users;

     public function addUser(User $user)
     {
         $user->setGroup($this);
         $this->users[] = $user;

         return $this;
     }
}
```

This should fixes your issue.

Comment: I had tried something very close to the above (except the `addUser` method), but without luck. However, your solution worked, so thank you very much for your help!